# ActiveJdbc open/close Db architecture

Tags: activejdbc

I'm building a webapp using ActiveJdbc. Everything works perfectly.
I just a "problem" with my architecture.

Using Spring 4, I have a filter where I open the connection, do what I have to do and then close it.

```
        try {

            Base.open(ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection(dbName));
            Base.openTransaction();
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
            Base.commitTransaction();
        } catch (IOException | ServletException e) {
            Base.rollbackTransaction();
            Logger.logMsg(Logger.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } finally {
            Base.close();
        }
```

The problem is I have: 
 - some controllers that don't need a connection.
 - A scheduler that needs a connection to instanciate a singleton
 - Some other classes that may need connection according to some parameters.

The result is I have this code above in several places. Is there a better way to do the connection only in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaLite has a considerable flexibility in opening/closing connections for different controllers: http://javalite.io/database_configuration#bind-connections-to-controllers

However, since you are not using [ActiveWeb](http://javalite.io/activeweb), you have to write your own logic. Basically, in your ServletFilter, you need to examine the URI and then make a decision to open a connection or skip.